# Apply 1 channel mask to 3 channel Tensor in tensorflow

Tags: mask, tensorflow

I'm trying to apply a mask (binary, only one channel) to an RGB image (3 channels, normalized to [0, 1]). My current solution is, that I split the RGB image into it's channels, multiply it with the mask and concatenate these channels again:

```py
with tf.variable_scope('apply_mask') as scope:
  # Output mask is in range [-1, 1], bring to range [0, 1] first
  zero_one_mask = (output_mask + 1) / 2
  # Apply mask to all channels.
  channels = tf.split(3, 3, output_img)
  channels = [tf.mul(c, zero_one_mask) for c in channels]
  output_img = tf.concat(3, channels)
```

However, this seems pretty inefficient, especially since, to my understanding, none of these computations are done in-place. Is there a more efficient way for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`tf.mul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#mul) operator supports [numpy-style broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which would allow you to simplify and optimize the code slightly.

Let's say that `zero_one_mask` is an `m x n` tensor, and `output_img` is a `b x m x n x 3` (where `b` is the batch size - I'm inferring this from the fact that you split `output_img` on dimension 3)*. You can use [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) to make `zero_one_mask` broadcastable to `channels`, by reshaping it to be an `m x n x 1` tensor:

```
with tf.variable_scope('apply_mask') as scope:
  # Output mask is in range [-1, 1], bring to range [0, 1] first
  # NOTE: Assumes `output_mask` is a 2-D `m x n` tensor.
  zero_one_mask = tf.expand_dims((output_mask + 1) / 2, 2)
  # Apply mask to all channels.
  # NOTE: Assumes `output_img` is a 4-D `b x m x n x c` tensor.
  output_img = tf.mul(output_img, zero_one_mask)
```

(* This would work equally if `output_img` were a 4-D `b x m x n x c` (for any number of channels `c`) or 3-D `m x n x c` tensor, due to the way broadcasting works.)

Comment: Is it somewhere documented that tensorflow supports this kind of broadcasting? I haven't come across it while reading the documentation...

Comment: I believe it's not - and indeed the docstrings for `tf.mul` etc. leave something to be desired. I've created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/508) for this, and it should be fixed in time for the next release.