# TensorFlow: Hadamard Product:: How do I get this?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow has the function:

```
tf.matmul
```

Which multiplies two vectors and produces a scalar.

However, I need to do the following:

```
# dense dim:  (?,227)
dense_part = tf.nn.relu(some stuff here)

# softmax matrix dim: (?,227,19) or (?,19,227) or (?,227,227), where I 
# ....can slice the last dim down to (?,227,19)
softmax_matrix = tf.matmul(dense_part,softmax_weight_variable)
```

However, there is nothing I can set softmax_weight_variable to in order to accomplish this with a matrix multiplication.  I need to use the "Tensor Product" (also called "Outer Product"...) but this function doesn't seem to be implemented.

How do I implement a Hadamard (element-wise) multiplication and Outer Product in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 8):

Elementwise multiplication of `x` and `y` is just [`tf.mul(x, y)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#mul). This also [supports NumPy-style broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220374/apply-1-channel-mask-to-3-channel-tensor-in-tensorflow/34220963), which you should be able to use to get an outer product if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

It is `tf.multiply` in Tensorflow 1.11. The functions provides Hadamard product of two tensors with equal shapes.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.4.1 of Tensorflow it looks like this function has been named [`tf.math.multiply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/multiply).