# Tensorflow, how to multiply a 2D tensor (matrix) by corresponding elements in a 1D vector

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have a 2D matrix `M` of shape `[batch x dim]`, I have a vector `V` of shape `[batch]`. How can I multiply each of the columns in the matrix by the corresponding element in the V? That is:

[image]

I know an inefficient numpy implementation would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 10))
V = np.random.randint(4)
def tst(M, V):
  rows = []
  for i in range(len(M)):
    col = []
    for j in range(len(M[i])):
      col.append(M[i][j] * V[i])
    rows.append(col)
  return np.array(rows)
```

In tensorflow, given two tensors, what is the most efficient way to achieve this?

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
M = tf.constant(np.random.normal(size=(4,10)), dtype=tf.float32)
V = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: But, shouldn't it then be `How can I multiply each of the **rows** in the matrix by the corresponding element in the V?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In NumPy, we would need to make `V` `2D` and then let broadcasting do the element-wise multiplication (i.e. Hadamard product). I am guessing, it should be the same on `tensorflow`. So, for expanding dims on `tensorflow`, we can use `tf.newaxis` (on newer versions) or `tf.expand_dims` or a reshape with `tf.reshape` -

```
tf.multiply(M, V[:,tf.newaxis])
tf.multiply(M, tf.expand_dims(V,1))
tf.multiply(M, tf.reshape(V, (-1, 1)))
```

Comment: This was my answer `mul = tf.multiply(M,tf.expand_dims(V, axis=1)).eval()` & `mul2= M.eval()* V.eval()[:,None]`, its been answered 6 mins ago. You are so fast

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Divakar's answer, I would like to make a note that the order of `M`  and `V` don't matter. It seems that `tf.multiply` also does [broadcasting during multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220963/2956066).

Example:

```
In [55]: M.eval()
Out[55]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)

In [56]: V.eval()
Out[56]: array([10, 20, 30], dtype=int32)

In [57]: tf.multiply(M, V[:,tf.newaxis]).eval()
Out[57]: 
array([[ 10,  20,  30,  40],
       [ 40,  60,  80, 100],
       [ 90, 120, 150, 180]], dtype=int32)

In [58]: tf.multiply(V[:, tf.newaxis], M).eval()
Out[58]: 
array([[ 10,  20,  30,  40],
       [ 40,  60,  80, 100],
       [ 90, 120, 150, 180]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: So, what is `order` here?

Comment: @Divakar I meant the order in which we pass to `tf.multiply`. But, just now figured out that `tf.multiply` is a hadamard product. So, it should not matter. my bad :( I figured this out now only

Comment: I see :)  Yeah. it shouldn't matter.