# How to do multiply each row of a matrix by different scalar in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a matrix `A` of dimension `(N,5)` and a vector `v` of dimension `(N,1)`. Is there any efficient way to obtain a  new matrix `B` of dimension `(N,5)` such that each row `B[i,:]=v[i]*A[i,:]` in tensorflow?

The known operation `tf.matmul` and `tf.multiply` don't support these kind of operations.

Comment: Really, `tf.multiply(A,v)` doesn't work?

Comment: Or would `v` be `1D` and not `2D`? If `1D`, try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817135/tensorflow-how-to-multiply-a-2d-tensor-matrix-by-corresponding-elements-in-a.

Comment: @Divakar: Yeah `v` is `1D`. I'll take a look